# Is there a formula that can be used to calculate the rate of non-nuclear spallation due to molecule-surface collisions?

Tags: vacuum, molecules

Spallation is an overloaded term and most articles discuss other forms of it (such as nuclear spallation or meteor impact) than the type that I would like to learn about.

I'm interested in spallation that occurs in a high-vacuum environment when a fast moving molecule glances off of a smooth hard surface. My concern is that under certain conditions, such as above a certain critical particle velocity, $v_S$, spallation will start to occur. Then molecules from the surface will be knocked free and begin to float around in the vacuum.

I would like to find a formula that describes the rate of spallation as a function of, for example, the particle velocity, angle of impact, smoothness of the surface, hardness of the surface, mass of the molecule, etc.

Also, if you know of other relevant tags or a term that describes the specific kind of spallation that I'm interested in, please let me know.

Comment: Lots of literature on sputter yields…

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks